# Fantasy book about a girl who can detect scribes and has a talking key

Tags: story-identification, books

It's about this girl that lives in an awful apartment, living in a bad place or something like that. She has these powers that could detect scribes and there's a talking key at one point. They are working together to end the world and their government or something.

Comment: “detect scribes”?  Like she can supernaturally tell whether someone is literate?  If “scribes” is not what you meant, can you paraphrase?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this?  Was it an e-book, a paperback or a hardcover?  Do you remember the cover art?  Any character or place names?  Is the setting contemporary, Victorian, mediaeval, feudal...?  Is it set in a city, a town, rural, wilderness....?

Comment: Perhaps "detect[ing] scribes" is the ability to sense the presence of journalists at a distance, the better to avoid them?

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 5):

If this is a very recent book, it might be [*Foundryside*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?2392759) (2018) by Robert Jackson Bennett.

The protagonist, Sancia Grado is a thief hired to steal a magical artifact that would allow the ruling Merchant Houses to rewrite the rules of the world itself.  This magical artifact turns out to be a talking key.  The magic of rewriting reality is called "scriving," which is close to "scribe."

Quoting from the blurb on [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/37007781-foundryside):

> But unbeknownst to her, Sancia's been sent to steal an artifact of unimaginable power, an object that could revolutionize the magical technology known as scriving. The Merchant Houses who control this magic--the art of using coded commands to imbue everyday objects with sentience--have already used it to transform Tevanne into a vast, remorseless capitalist machine. But if they can unlock the artifact's secrets, they will rewrite the world itself to suit their aims.

[image: U.S. cover of "Foundryside" showing a black-dressed figure sitting in a window overlooking a burning city]
[image: U.K. cover of "Foundryside" showing a black-cloaked figure walking along a misty Victorian-looking streetscape]

<sub>For all this received a few nominations, I hadn't heard of it 'til now.  Found using the search `site:goodreads.com/book "talking key"` where it was one of a very few hits.</sub>